# mongo post hook aggregation pipeline not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am doing a social media and i have a problem with 2 schemas. User and followers. when a user follows another, a new document is added to followers method with who dollows who information. After the document is created a post hook runs with a statics function with agregattion pipeline that calculate the followers of the followed user and the following of the following user and after modyfy it, Till that its right but when i try to do the same when a user unfollow other, this post hook dont works correctly.

followerschema.statics function with agregation pipeline:

```
followersschema.statics.AdjustFollowersFollowing = async function(FOLLOWEDID,FOLLOWINGID){
    try{const statsfollowedid = await this.aggregate([{ //THIS AGREGATION PIPELINE GETS THE EXACT NUMBER OF FOLLOWERS THAT THE FOLLOWED USER HAS
        $match: { followedid : FOLLOWEDID}
    },{
        $group: {
            _id: FOLLOWEDID,
            numFollowed: {$sum:1}
        }
    }]);

    const statsfollowingid = await this.aggregate([{//THIS AGREGGATION PIPELINE GETS THE EXACT NUMBER OF PERSON THAT FOLLOWS THE FOLLOWING USER 
        $match: { followingid : FOLLOWINGID}
    },{
        $group: {
            _id: FOLLOWINGID,
            numFollowing: {$sum:1}
        }
    }]);

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id : FOLLOWEDID},{numfollowers:statsfollowedid[0].numFollowed})
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id : FOLLOWINGID},{numfollowing:statsfollowingid[0].numFollowing})
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    
    
}
```

i am trying to create an agregation pipeline for a post hook of .findOneAndRemove method mongoose. first i tryed doing this on a post hook.(the same code works on the hook .pre('save)

this._conditions got the info of before deleted

```
followersschema.post('findOneAndRemove',function(){ 
    console.log(this._conditions.followedid); console.log(this._conditions.followingid)                                                                                                    //execute function for AdjustFollowersFollowing of both users after unfollow
    this.constructor.AdjustFollowersFollowing(this._conditions.followedid,this._conditions.followingid) 
});
```

the error message that i got is:

TypeError: this.constructor.AdjustFollowersFollowing is not a function

up is what i tryed also

what i tryed to do next is up

Answer (score 0):

try to use some node packages like expressjs, express has some functions you can use to fix your problem.
you can install by run this in terminal:

`npm init -y`

`npm -i express`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).